# How to construct a simple homotopy between a Jordan curve and a circle inside it?

Tags: complex-analysis, homotopy-theory

Let $\gamma: S^1 \mapsto \mathbb R^2$ be a simple closed curve (with positive orientation) in the plane that contains the origin in its interior. I would like to prove that it is homotopic to a small cocentric circle (in the punctured plane) with positive orientation, i.e, there is a continuous map $ [0,1]^2 \ni (s,t) \mapsto H(s,t) $ such that

$$ H(0,t) = \gamma (t), \quad H(1,t) = re^{2\pi it}, \quad \text{for some} \quad r >0.  $$

So I consulted this post [Homotopy of Jordan Curves?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3691883/homotopy-of-jordan-curves), I understand that if we find a homotopy between $\gamma$ and a bigger circle in the exterior of $\gamma$ and then use the standard homotopy between circles to finish the construction, but I hope to get a much simpler argument (if there is any!) in this thread. Any hints are highly appreciated!

Comment: **Homotopic** where? Do you mean homotopic in the entire plane? Then just use the straight line homotopy between two maps $S^1\to R^2$. The fact that $\gamma$ is simple plays no role in the construction.

Comment: @MoisheKohan added "(in the punctured plane)", that's why I mentioned the origin is inside $\gamma$ :)

Comment: 1. Your definition of a homotopy of two maps is wrong (you would be better off working with maps of $S^1$ instead of an interval). 2. The homotopy in the punctured plane may not exist: It depends on the orientation of your Jordan curve.

Comment: @MoisheKohan., thanks for pointing out. It seems that I lack a lot of knowledge on this topic, I was just curious about this question. I will try to modify one final time ,if it's still wrong or not clear, I think I will delete this post instead :(. Btw, could you help me understand why $S^1$ is correct but the interval is not?

Answer (score 0):

By the Jordan curve theorem, $\text{ext}(\gamma)$ is connected and therefore $\overline{\text{ext}(\gamma)} = \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \text{int}(\gamma)$ is connected.  So then by 7 => 1 here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem, $\text{int}(\gamma)$ is simply connected. Then just make a perturbation argument to show that $\gamma \sim \gamma'$ where $\gamma'$ lies inside $\text{int}(\gamma).$ For example, if $\gamma$ is a smooth curve, then for each point $p$ on $\gamma$, just perturb $\gamma$ in the direction of the normal vector pointing towards the interior region. In general, this seems to follow from the proof of the Jordan curve theorem, namely, the homology version shows $H_1 = 0$. Alternately, via the Riemann mapping theorem, there is a map $\phi \colon \text{int}(\gamma) \to D$ that extends to a map $\overline{\text{int}(\gamma)} \to \overline{D}$. So given a homotopy $H$ in $D$, $\phi^{-1} \circ H \circ \phi$ is a homotopy in $ \text{int}(\gamma)$. Either way, the crux of the argument is that the Jordan curve theorem implies there are two connected components that are relatively "nice". This doesn't construct such a homotopy, but I imagine that would be difficult depending on the complexity of $\gamma$.